# Call PowerShell script PS1 from another PS1 script inside Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell

I want call execution for a myScript1.ps1 script inside a second myScript2.ps1 script inside Powershell ISE.

The following code inside MyScript2.ps1, works fine from Powershell Administration, but doesn't work inside PowerShell ISE:

```
#Call myScript1 from myScript2
invoke-expression -Command .\myScript1.ps1
```

I obtain the following error when I execute MyScript2.ps1 from PowerShell ISE:

> The term '.\myScript1.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

In order run a script in the same directory.

In **PowerShell 3.0** and later you can use the automatic variable `$PSScriptRoot`:

```
$PSScriptRoot/myScript1.ps1
```

In **PowerShell 1.0 and 2.0** you should use this specific property:

```
& "$(Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)/myScript1.ps1"
```

---

The reason you should use that and not anything else can be illustrated with this example script.

```
## ScriptTest.ps1
Write-Host "InvocationName:" $MyInvocation.InvocationName
Write-Host "Path:" $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

Here are some results.

```
PS C:\Users\JasonAr> .\ScriptTest.ps1
InvocationName: .\ScriptTest.ps1
Path: C:\Users\JasonAr\ScriptTest.ps1

PS C:\Users\JasonAr> . .\ScriptTest.ps1
InvocationName: .
Path: C:\Users\JasonAr\ScriptTest.ps1

PS C:\Users\JasonAr> & ".\ScriptTest.ps1"
InvocationName: &
Path: C:\Users\JasonAr\ScriptTest.ps1
```

In **PowerShell 3.0** and later you can use the automatic variable `$PSScriptRoot`:

```
## ScriptTest.ps1
Write-Host "Script:" $PSCommandPath
Write-Host "Path:" $PSScriptRoot
```

```
PS C:\Users\jarcher> .\ScriptTest.ps1
Script: C:\Users\jarcher\ScriptTest.ps1
Path: C:\Users\jarcher
```

Comment: A late addition: If you're worried abot variance (or, actually, just want "solid" code) you probably want to use "Write-Output" rather than "Write-Host".

Comment: It would be good to see an example use of Split-Path in the answer. You also need to show calling a script inside another script really.

Comment: This is in absolutely no way an answer to the question asked. You are simply explaining how to find the path of the currently executing script, while the question is how to execute a separate script within the one currently executing. It's baffling to see this has been upvoted more than 100 times...

Comment: It absolutely does answer the question.  The piece the questioner was missing was how to find the location of a sibling script in order to run it.  The questioner accepted my answer since it helped them solve their problem.

Comment: You need to preface any variable with "& ". In this example it would be: "& $PSScriptRoot/myScript1.ps1"

Answer (score 112):

I am calling myScript1.ps1 from myScript2.ps1 .

Assuming both of the script are at the same location, first get the location of the script by using this command :

```
$PSScriptRoot
```

And, then, append the script name you want to call like this :

```
& "$PSScriptRoot\myScript1.ps1"
```

This should work.

Comment: `& "$PSScriptRoot\myScript1.ps1"` is enough

Comment: `& $PSScriptRoot\myScript1.ps1` IS enough (without quotes)

Comment: @GregorSimončič Only if the variable doesn't include whitespace characters. If the variable contains whitespace, the unquoted command would probably introduce a syntax error due to "splitting" the command into two pieces. Keeping the quotes is the safest way to go.

Answer (score 45):

The current path of MyScript1.ps1 is not the same as myScript2.ps1. You can get the folder path of  MyScript2.ps1 and concatenate it to MyScript1.ps1 and then execute it. Both scripts must be in the same location.

```
## MyScript2.ps1 ##
$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName
& "$ScriptPath\MyScript1.ps1"
```

Comment: How I have to initialize $MyInvocation variable?

Comment: You don't, it's an automatic variable.

Comment: It works, but obtain the following error before really execution of called script:

Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At line:4 char:25
+ $ScriptPath = Split-Path <<<<  $MyInvocation.InvocationName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Split-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SplitPathCommand

Comment: create a new script put: $MyInvocation.InvocationName in it and run the script. Do you get the path of the script?

Comment: @JasonMArcher - Why instead? As far as I know both give the same output?

Comment: Added an answer to explain things.

Answer (score 23):

One line solution:

```
& ((Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName) + "\MyScript1.ps1")
```

Comment: This is nice, but why not just `& '.\MyScript1.ps'` if the script resides in the same directory?

Comment: That's using current directory not script directory. Sure they're often the same ... but not always!

Comment: I question the same line - if you run a "Set-Location" command to move to that folder before you call it, that should achieve both by setting the location and making it current at the same time.

Comment: Firstly, that's not one-line any more :). But also, it's only applicable if you don't mind changing the working directory, which is quite the assumption and not good practice.

Answer (score 18):

This is just additional info to answers
in order to pass argument into the another file

Where you expect argument

**PrintName.ps1**

```
Param(
    [Parameter( Mandatory = $true)]
    $printName = "Joe"    
)


Write-Host $printName
```

**How to call the file**

```
Param(
    [Parameter( Mandatory = $false)]
    $name = "Joe"    
)


& ((Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName) + "\PrintName.ps1") -printName $name
```

If you do not do not provide any input it will default to "Joe" and this will be passed as argument into printName argument in **PrintName.ps1** file
which will in turn print out the **"Joe"** string

Answer (score 9):

To execute easily a script file in the same folder (or subfolder of) as the caller you can use this:

```
# Get full path to the script:
$ScriptRoute = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, "Scriptname.ps1"))

# Execute script at location:
&"$ScriptRoute"
```

Answer (score 5):

You may have found the answer for it already, but here is what I do.

I usually place this line at the beginning of my installation scripts:

```
if(!$PSScriptRoot){ $PSScriptRoot = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent } #In case if $PSScriptRoot is empty (version of powershell V.2).
```

Then I can use $PSScriptRoot variable as a location of the current script(path), like in the example bellow:

```
if(!$PSScriptRoot){ $PSScriptRoot = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent } #In case if $PSScriptRoot is empty (version of powershell V.2).  

Try {
If (Test-Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)') {
    $ChromeInstallArgs= "/i", "$PSScriptRoot\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64_v.57.0.2987.110.msi", "/q", "/norestart", "/L*v `"C:\Windows\Logs\Google_Chrome_57.0.2987.110_Install_x64.log`""
    Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList $ChromeInstallArgs -Wait -ErrorAction Stop
    $Result= [System.Environment]::ExitCode
} Else {
    $ChromeInstallArgs= "/i", "$PSScriptRoot\googlechromestandaloneenterprise_v.57.0.2987.110.msi", "/q", "/norestart", "/L*v `"C:\Windows\Logs\Google_Chrome_57.0.2987.110_Install_x86.log`""
    Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList $ChromeInstallArgs -Wait -ErrorAction Stop
    $Result= [System.Environment]::ExitCode
    }

} ### End Try block


Catch  {
    $Result = [System.Environment]::Exitcode
    [System.Environment]::Exit($Result)
   }
[System.Environment]::Exit($Result)
```

In your case, you can replace

*Start-process...*     line with

*Invoke-Expression $PSScriptRoot\ScriptName.ps1*

You can read more about $MYINVOCATION and $PSScriptRoot automatic variables on the Microsoft site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables

Answer (score 4):

I submit my example for consideration. This is how I call some code from a controller script in the tools I make. The scripts that do the work also need to accept parameters as well, so this example shows how to pass them. It does assume the script being called is in the same directory as the controller script (script making the call).

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[string[]]
$Computername,

[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[DateTime]
$StartTime,

[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[DateTime]
$EndTime
)

$ZAEventLogDataSplat = @{
    "Computername" = $Computername
    "StartTime"    = $StartTime
    "EndTime"      = $EndTime
}

& "$PSScriptRoot\Get-ZAEventLogData.ps1" @ZAEventLogDataSplat
```

The above is a controller script that accepts 3 parameters. These are defined in the param block. The controller script then calls the script named Get-ZAEventLogData.ps1. For the sake of example, this script also accepts the same 3 parameters. When the controller script calls to the script that does the work, it needs to call it and pass the parameters. The above shows how I do it by splatting.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and solved it this way.

My working directory is a general script folder and serveral particular script folder in same root, i need to call particular script folder (which call general script with the parameter of the particular problem).
So working directory is like this

```
\Nico\Scripts\Script1.ps1
             \Script2.ps1
      \Problem1\Solution1.ps1
               \ParameterForSolution1.config
      \Problem2\Solution2.ps1
               \ParameterForSolution2.config
```

Solutions1 and Solutions2 call the PS1 in Scripts folder loading the parameter stored in ParameterForSolution.
So in powershell ISE i run this command

```
.\Nico\Problem1\Solution1.PS1
```

And the code inside Solution1.PS1 is:

```
# This is the path where my script is running
$path = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

# Change to root dir
cd "$path\..\.."

$script = ".\Script\Script1.PS1"

$parametro = "Problem1\ParameterForSolution1.config"
# Another set of parameter Script1.PS1 can receive for debuggin porpuose
$parametro +=' -verbose'

Invoke-Expression "$script $parametro"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with this.  I didn't use any clever `$MyInvocation` stuff to fix it though.  If you open the ISE by right clicking a script file and selecting `edit` then open the second script from within the ISE you can invoke one from the other by just using the normal **.\script.ps1** syntax.
My guess is that the ISE has the notion of a current folder and opening it like this sets the current folder to the folder containing the scripts.
When I invoke one script from another in normal use I just use **.\script.ps1**, IMO it's wrong to modify the script just to make it work in the ISE properly...

Comment: Downvoted this because the issue is the failure of the script to work when not run from the folder containing it. It's not about modifying the script to work in the ISE specifically, it's about modifying the script to be portable and flexible enough to handle being run from a different directory. The behavior of the code in this case shouldn't depend on where you've invoked it from.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following commands:

```
$Patch = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "\patch.ps1"<br>
Invoke-Expression "& `"$Patch`""
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you run PowerShell built-in scripts inside of your scripts?

How do you use built-in scripts like

```
Get-Location
pwd
ls
dir
split-path
::etc...
```

Those are ran by your computer, automatically checking the path of the script.

Similarly, I can run my custom scripts by just putting the name of the script in the script-block

```
::sid.ps1 is a PS script I made to find the SID of any user
::it takes one argument, that argument would be the username
echo $(sid.ps1 jowers)


(returns something like)> S-X-X-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX


$(sid.ps1 jowers).Replace("S","X")

(returns same as above but with X instead of S)
```

Go on to the powershell command line and type

```
> $profile
```

This will return the path to a file that our PowerShell command line will execute every time you open the app.

It will look like this

```
C:\Users\jowers\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
```

Go to Documents and see if you already have a WindowsPowerShell directory. I didn't, so

```
> cd \Users\jowers\Documents
> mkdir WindowsPowerShell
> cd WindowsPowerShell
> type file > Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
```

We've now created the script that will launch every time we open the PowerShell App.

The reason we did that was so that we could add our own folder that holds all of our custom scripts. Let's create that folder and I'll name it "Bin" after the directories that Mac/Linux hold its scripts in.

```
> mkdir \Users\jowers\Bin
```

Now we want that directory to be added to our `$env:path` variable every time we open the app so go back to the `WindowsPowerShell` Directory and

```
> start Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
```

Then add this

```
$env:path += ";\Users\jowers\Bin"
```

Now the shell will automatically find your commands, as long as you save your scripts in that "Bin" directory.

Relaunch the powershell and it should be one of the first scripts that execute.

Run this on the command line after reloading to see your new directory in your path variable:

```
> $env:Path
```

Now we can call our scripts from the command line or from within another script as simply as this:

```
$(customScript.ps1 arg1 arg2 ...)
```

As you see we must call them with the `.ps1` extension until we make aliases for them. If we want to get fancy.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this, there is a lot here.  But there are 9 other answers already here.  How does this differ?  What additional information is it providing?

Comment: Doing this allows us to use our custom-scripts inside of other scripts—in the same way that built-in scripts are used inside of our scripts. Do this and as long as you save your scripts in the directory that you put in your path, the computer will automatically find the path of the custom-script when you use it on the command line or in another script

Answer (score 0):

If the vars above are null, you are probably using PowerShell ISE. In this case try:

```js
if ($psISE)
{
    Split-Path -Path $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath        
}
else
{
    $global:PSScriptRoot
}
```

Check out this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474074/powershell-psscriptroot-is-null).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
start powershell {./script.ps1}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?