# PowerShell PSScriptRoot is null

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

When I run `$PSScriptRoot` it returns `null`. I am using PS version 4.

```
$val  = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi
```

Error

> Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an
>   empty string.

Comment: Do you execute this in PowerShell ISE?

Answer (score 23):

If using ISE use:

`$psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath`

When ISE is launched, $psISE is created and can be used to determine the current path of the ISE instance. This was introduced in version 3.0.

See [**ISE Object Model Hierarchy**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/the-ise-object-model-hierarchy?view=powershell-4.0)

If you wanted to get the path in either shell or ISE you could use something like this:

```
if ($psISE)
{
    Split-Path -Path $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath        
}
else
{
    $global:PSScriptRoot
}
```

Comment: $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath does not show the file path if the file is called from another powershell script

Answer (score 14):

You have to make sure that this expression is in a saved .ps1 script.

This can happened in following cases:

- You use this statement in PowerShell ISE console
- You use this statement in PowerShell console without a script file
- You marked only this expression for execution in PowerShell ISE

Comment: Then how to debug the script in ISE...?

Comment: I guess it can't be set while debugging either as the value is ignored, then heads up if you change the script it will be forcefully saved in order to debug.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$PWD.Path
```

It works in PowerShell ISE and Powershell Console. It returns the Present Working Directory.

$PSScriptRoot is the Root Path of where the current script is saved. When used in a command it will return blank as there is no script who's current path you are looking for.

Comment: Works in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell Core.