# $PsScriptRoot null in ps 2.0

Tags: powershell

While this [Powershell PSScriptRoot is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474074/powershell-psscriptroot-is-null) (pasted below for an easy read) seems to answer the question it does not in my case.

> You have to make sure that this expression is in a saved .ps1 script.
>
> This can happened in following cases:
>
> You use this statement in PowerShell ISE console You use this
>   statement in PowerSehll console without a script file You marked only
>   this expression for execution in PowerShell ISE

I am running the ps in a .ps1 file outside the ISE and still getting a null pointer.

Comment: `$PsScriptRoot` in PowerShell v2 work only inside `.psm1` script module files, but not inside `.ps1` ordinary script files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the file system location of a PowerShell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667238/how-can-i-get-the-file-system-location-of-a-powershell-script)

Answer (score 3):

`$PSScriptRoot` is an automatic variable introduced in PowerShell v3.