# Copy Files from a Folder With in a Folder

Tags: powershell

Hello Guys i would like your help in the following. I have a folder that contains some msi files that i am installing with powershell. the code is as follows.

```
Start-Process -FilePath $(Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "VS2010_Runtimes_x86.msi") -ArgumentList '/qb' -Wait
```

i use the same command to install the rest of the msi files. I have a different folder thats called Project that lives inside the original folder. I would like to copy all the files that are inside project folder to a different directory.

```
Copy-Item -Path $(Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "Project") -Destination "C:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett Packard Enterprise\Records Manager" -Recurse
```

The code for copying files does not work :(

My entire code is:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $(Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "VS2010_Runtimes_x86.msi") -ArgumentList '/qb' -Wait
Start-Process -FilePath $(Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "VS2013_Runtimes_x86.msi") -ArgumentList '/qb' -Wait
Start-Process -FilePath $(Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "HPE_RM_x86.msi") -ArgumentList '/qb' -Wait

Remove-Item 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\HPE RM Queue Processor.lnk'
Remove-Item 'C:\Users\Public\Desktop\HPE RM Desktop.lnk'

Copy-Item -Path $(Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "Project") -Destination "C:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett Packard Enterprise\Records Manager" -Recurse
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, can you run the `Copy-Item` with the `-Verbose` switch and include the output in your question?

Comment: Please elaborate on "does not work".  Is your code running under an account that can write files to a subdirectory of ``C:\Program Files (x86)\``?

Comment: it does not copy files, i get an error message
Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.

Comment: @BACON yes, my account has rights. i am an admin on the computer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474074/powershell-psscriptroot-is-null

Comment: Your `Start-Process` lines should also fail with the same error. Can you include the entire output in your question please.

Comment: @mjsqu Start-Process does not fail. it executes installation of the msi just fine. When i run single line of code that should copy files from Project Folder i get the following error.
Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At line:1 char:35
+ Copy-Item -Path $(Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "Project") ...
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindin
if this is not the correct way of copying the files, what would be the correct way?

Comment: I would extract your project path resolution into a separate line so you can print and verify that the result of `Join-Path` is what you expect it to be (e.g. `$projectPath = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "Project"; Write-Host "\`$projectPath: $projectPath"; Copy-Item -Path $project Path -Destination '...' -Recurse`); evidently it's somehow an empty string.  No idea why `Join-Path` would work in the prior invocation of `Start-Process` but not when passed to `Copy-Item`, but that's just something that'll have to be debugged.  Also, those error details should be added to the question.