# Run a test in PowerShell with $PSScriptRoot raises an error

Tags: pester

I want to create a test with Pester. I have to create some files and then read them with a filter.

The problem I get is when I use `$PSScriptRoot`. If I run the test in the Windows PowerShell ISE, it is working.

[image]

The same test in a PowerShell using

```
Invoke-Pester -Output Detailed .\MyTest.Tests.ps1
```

returns an error:

> ParameterBindingValidationException: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

The `$path` is defined `$targetPath = $PSScriptRoot`. I tried to use `$psISE` like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474074/powershell-psscriptroot-is-null) with the same result. Also I noticed that `$psISE` returns the path of Pester and not the local path (in the screenshot below *C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\5.4.1*).

[image]

How can I fix the script to run it with Windows PowerShell ISE, PowerShell and also in an Azure pipeline?

Comment: Its difficult to assist without you providing some code we can use to reproduce the problem. However if your use of $PSScriptRoot is just to set a folder for creating/modifying/deleting test files, consider using TestDrive:\ (also available as $TestDrive) instead: https://pester.dev/docs/usage/testdrive

Comment: Variables set in the `BeforeDiscovery` fase are defined in another scope than the `BeforeAll` step. Make sure you set `$targetPath = $PSScriptRoot` within the `BeforeAll` scope