# Can't declare methods in a script being run in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm invoking a script as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-Expression?view=powershell-7#example-2--run-a-script-on-the-local-computer) and exemplified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6816450/1525840). It's running and I can see the outputs to the console (both *hazaa* and *shazoo*). However, the method declared in it does not appear to be there, despite testing both versions below.

```
Invoke-Expression -Command $target
$target | Invoke-Expression
```

The contents of the file are like this.

```
Write-Host "Hazaa"
function TestPower { Write-Host "I got the power..." }
Write-Host "Shazoo"
```

When I execute the same function definition in the console, it's there, working fine. I'm not getting any errors on the manual execution nor the invokation from the other file. No warnings neither.

The weirdest part is that the function definitions done in the invoking script (i.d. the one that the invokes the execution not the one that in being targeted for the invokation).

Comment: "it does not appear to be there" - there's nothing in the file that would tell you either way, so how did you reach that conclusion? And what is `$target`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I try to execute a function in the invoking script and it works, giving me the expected printout. Then, I execute a function contained in the invoked script and get an error telling me that it't not there. As for the second question, since the script is being invoked (which we know because there's a printout), the exact content of the path in *$target* seems irrelevant. Lets say it's *c:\temp\beep.ps1*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To rephrase your issue - a function defined in a script invoked with `Invoke-Expression` isn't available after the expression has executed, i.e.:

**test.ps1**

```bsh
Write-Host "Hazaa"
function TestPower { Write-Host "I got the power..." }
Write-Host "Shazoo"
```

**Interactive**

```bsh
PS> Invoke-Expression -Command "C:\src\so\test.ps1"
PS> TestPower
TestPower : The term 'TestPower' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ testpower
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (testpower:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

You can fix this by [dot-sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) the script in the expression instead:

```bsh
PS> Invoke-Expression -Command ". 'C:\src\so\test.ps1'"
Hazaa
Shazoo
PS> TestPower
I got the power...
```

Note that the documentation for [script scope and dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) says:

> Each script runs in its own scope. The functions, variables, aliases, and drives that are created in the script exist only in the script scope. You cannot access these items or their values in the scope in which the script runs.

Which explains why `TestPower` isn't available outside of your `Invoke-Expression` because the script is running in its own scope.

By contrast, using dot sourcing:

> The dot sourcing feature lets you run a script in the current scope instead of in the script scope. ... After the script runs, you can use the created items and access their values in your session.

Comment: This is one kick-ass answer regarding clarity and consideration for the provided facts. If it works (I haven't tested yet but I'm sure it's going to resolve my issue), you not only helped me for this case but also educated me on dot-sourcing, which I've never heard of before. As such, i working, you'll be getting the sweet, sweet strike of bounty apart from greeny checky and plussy-one-y.

Comment: Absolutely kick-ass'y. Accepting as correct answer and smacking you with a bounty (in 2 days, though, due to limitation of SO). I'm cheap AF so it's the minimum 50 rep only but feel privileged - given how rarely I do it, it's like 500 in normal peoples rep.   :)

Comment: Damn, I almost forgot. I had to wait two days to start the bounty. Now I have to wait additional day to award it. Just in case I forget, please do remind me. I'd hate to see it not awarded to you. You do deserve it and I'm forgetful AF, due to medical reasons. You will not be seen as a naggy beggar or rep junkie, whatsoever.